# how to adapt kettlebell exercises for muscle endurance

Tags: workout-routines, muscle-endurance, kettlebell

I want to work on building more muscle endurance, because I do a lot of long hiking. Hikes can last for a few hours, so I find that my back and hips and legs start to fatigue after walking for a couple of hours.

I was reading a couple of articles about muscle endurance workouts but I am still a bit confused about how to adapt exercises/workouts for muscle endurance.

https://www.verywellfit.com/what-is-muscular-endurance-3120360
https://www.mensjournal.com/health-fitness/3-day-workout-program-build-muscle-endurance-and-get-fighting-shape/

So I was thinking that I would change up my kettlebell workout a bit to include some additonal exercises. Kettlebell swings already work muscle endurance, but I wanted to target some additional muscles for the endurance benefits.

I have a 25kg/55 lbs kettlebell that I use for single arm swings without too much trouble, but I was thinking that I would alternate between kettlbell swings and kettlebell windmills. The challenge is that for windmills I definitely need to use less weight, but then my swings will feel a bit diminished.

So I was not sure if reducing the weight is the way to go? I have a 20lb kettlbell, so I could do swings and then windmills with that. I am sure that mixing these two exercises would probably by plenty strenuous, but I am just not used to going down in weight like that--so just wanted to make sure that this approach makes sense, or wanted to ask if there is a better way.

Is the correct approach to just try the adjustment and see how I feel? And then if the new approach feels fine, then just monitor and measure whether I am getting the endurance benefits I am looking for--with respect to hiking.